# Firestore security rules to count documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to limit the number of documents a user can have in a collection.

I expect that having a limit of let's say 100 documents when a user tries to create the document 101 gets an error.

Is there a way of doing this using firestore security rules ?

Comment: Does the user communicates directly with the firestore db when creating a document or do you use the admin sdk?

Answer (score 1):

Security rules don't have the capability to count the number of documents in a collection.  In fact, counting documents in Firestore is, in general, is kind of a difficult problem that typically requires some support from a product like Cloud Functions.

If you want to get something like this to work, you will have to [write some Firestore triggers in Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) that manages the count of documents by triggering some code when a document is created or deleted.  This count would have to be stored in another document in another collection.  Then, the contents of that document could be used in security rules to limit client access.

Comment: Keep in mind that there's a latency in a Cloud Function trigger, so, the count field on a document is most probably not yet updated when the security rules evaluate it. You can, however, offset it so that the Security Rules evaluate it correctly.

Comment: @Jeboy Actually, for low volume writes, it's perfectly doable to keep a transactionally accurate count, enforced by security rules, using the solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59924062/how-do-you-force-a-firestore-client-app-to-maintain-a-correct-document-count-for

Comment: Whatever the size of the write transaction, it has 3 to 4-second latency (for just 1 update operation) before the trigger kicks-in, it is documented here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events "It can take up to 10 seconds for a function to respond to changes in Cloud Firestore.".

So, Security Rules will always run first.

Comment: @Jeboy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59924062/how-do-you-force-a-firestore-client-app-to-maintain-a-correct-document-count-for

Comment: `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/messages-stats/data).data.count + 1`

That's what I'm saying to offset, in my first comment