# Easiest way to synchronize a Document across multiple Collections in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

Suppose I have two top-level collections, `users` and `companies`. The `companies` collection contains a sub collection of Users, called `employees`. What's the most simple way to ensure that User records in the `users` and `companies/employees` paths are synchronized? Is it more common to use batch operations or a trigger function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your document writes are coming directly from your client app, you can use [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to make sure that all documents have the same values as part of a batch write.  If you write the rules correctly, it will force the client to make appropriate batch writes at all required locations, assuming that you have a well-defined document structure.

You can see a similar example of this technique in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59924062/how-do-you-force-a-firestore-client-app-to-maintain-a-correct-document-count-for) that ensures that clients increment and decrement a document counter with each create and delete. Your rules will obviously be more complex.

Since security rules *only apply to client code*, there are no similar techniques for backend code.  If you're writing code on the backend, you just have to make sure your code for batch writes are all correct.

I see no need to trigger a Cloud Function if you're able to do a batch write, as the batch will take effect atomically and immediately, while the function will have some latency, and possibly incur a race condition, since you don't have a guaranteed order of execution.

Comment: What if the document writes are not coming from the client? Say for example, if I run some SaaS and only want clients I add myself using the app? Throw some javascript up as a Function and call that?

Comment: Then that's the backend case I was talking about.  You can still do a batch write, but you will have to verify that your code is correct - nothing will be able to 'check' your work like security rules.

Comment: That's a bit of a bummer, but I guess it's just a limitation of Firestore. Thanks!